# Rails and Active Record STI Cat and Dog each has a buddy, can ActiveRelation handle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to use STI to relate one object on one side of the tree to the other.  What I'd like to do is below.  Specific questions, Should I use has_one, belongs_to?  What else is required to make it when one is updated the other sees this relation?

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Cat < Animal
  has_one :buddy # this is buddy_id, and has to be a dog
end

class Dog < Animal
  has_one :buddy # this should reference the other side? and should be a cat
end
```

Comment: could you describe the relation, a buddy could have a cat or a dog right? is there a relation between a cat and a dog? cause you sounded like there might be.

Comment: A cat has a single buddy and must be dog.  Once assigned a dog, the cat should also be the dog's #buddy

Answer (score 0):

Just make one of them belong to the other, and the other will have one of the first, assuming the cat is the one that has the id field

```
class Cat < Animal
  belongs_to :buddy, class_name: Dog.name
end

class Dog < Animal
  has_one :buddy, class_name: Cat.name
end
```